# ¿Como obtengo la data de un segmento en una grafica con chartjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Tengo una gráfica que me funciona bien, pero no encuentro como obtener la data de un segmento al momento de dar un clic, quisiera obtener datos como **id**, **texto**, **precio**, etc...

```js
let datos = {
  "labels": [
    "Bebidas Frias",
    "Bebidas Calientes",
    "ceviche",
    "Postres"
  ],
  "data": [
    271,
    324,
    458,
    1355
  ],
  "data_info": [
    {
      "id": 66,
      "nombre": "Bebidas Frias",
      "id_padre": 0,
      "productos": [
        {
          "id": 407,
          "text": "Frugos",
          "precio": 12,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 66,
          "cantidad": "98",
          "promedio_ta": 65.96,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 412,
          "text": "Inka Cola 1L",
          "precio": 14,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 66,
          "cantidad": "77",
          "promedio_ta": 0,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 413,
          "text": "Cola Inglesa 3L",
          "precio": 20,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 66,
          "cantidad": "96",
          "promedio_ta": 59.45,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        }
      ],
      "cantidad": 271,
      "promedio_ta": 125.41,
      "promedio_tp": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 67,
      "nombre": "Bebidas Calientes",
      "id_padre": 0,
      "productos": [
        {
          "id": 410,
          "text": "Café",
          "precio": 4,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 67,
          "cantidad": "197",
          "promedio_ta": 0,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 411,
          "text": "Té",
          "precio": 7,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 67,
          "cantidad": "127",
          "promedio_ta": 0,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        }
      ],
      "cantidad": 324,
      "promedio_ta": 0,
      "promedio_tp": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 74,
      "nombre": "ceviche",
      "id_padre": 0,
      "productos": [
        {
          "id": 275,
          "text": "Arroz con mariscos",
          "precio": 35,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 74,
          "cantidad": "389",
          "promedio_ta": 21.91,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 475,
          "text": "cebiche guerrero",
          "precio": 34,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 74,
          "cantidad": "57",
          "promedio_ta": 277.47,
          "promedio_tp": 17.89
        },
        {
          "id": 858,
          "text": "Lomo saltado",
          "precio": 75,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 74,
          "cantidad": "12",
          "promedio_ta": 579.08,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        }
      ],
      "cantidad": 458,
      "promedio_ta": 878.46,
      "promedio_tp": 17.89
    },
    {
      "id": 51,
      "nombre": "Postres",
      "id_padre": 0,
      "productos": [
        {
          "id": 310,
          "text": "Mazañorra morada",
          "precio": 20,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 51,
          "cantidad": "397",
          "promedio_ta": 51.26,
          "promedio_tp": 0.01
        },
        {
          "id": 311,
          "text": "Leche asada",
          "precio": 5,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 51,
          "cantidad": "282",
          "promedio_ta": 119.17,
          "promedio_tp": 0.01
        },
        {
          "id": 312,
          "text": "Flan",
          "precio": 24,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 51,
          "cantidad": "256",
          "promedio_ta": 107.63,
          "promedio_tp": 1.28
        },
        {
          "id": 313,
          "text": "Arroz zambito",
          "precio": 27,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 51,
          "cantidad": "190",
          "promedio_ta": 137.52,
          "promedio_tp": 0.01
        },
        {
          "id": 314,
          "text": "Manzana acaramelada",
          "precio": 15,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 51,
          "cantidad": "84",
          "promedio_ta": 57.9,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 435,
          "text": "Alfajore",
          "precio": 11,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 51,
          "cantidad": "139",
          "promedio_ta": 195.73,
          "promedio_tp": 0.01
        },
        {
          "id": 854,
          "text": "Pecho broaster",
          "precio": 10,
          "fk_id_producto_categoria": 51,
          "cantidad": "7",
          "promedio_ta": 111.43,
          "promedio_tp": 0
        }
      ],
      "cantidad": 1355,
      "promedio_ta": 780.6400000000001,
      "promedio_tp": 1.32
    }
  ]
};

var graphColors = [];
var graphOutlines = [];
var hoverColor = [];

var internalDataLength = datos['data'].length;
i = 0;
while (i <= internalDataLength) {
    var randomR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
    var randomG = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
    var randomB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
  
    var graphBackground = "rgb(" 
            + randomR + ", " 
            + randomG + ", " 
            + randomB + ")";
    graphColors.push(graphBackground);
    
    var graphOutline = "rgb(" 
            + (randomR - 80) + ", " 
            + (randomG - 80) + ", " 
            + (randomB - 80) + ")";
    graphOutlines.push(graphOutline);
    
    var hoverColors = "rgb(" 
            + (randomR + 25) + ", " 
            + (randomG + 25) + ", " 
            + (randomB + 25) + ")";
    hoverColor.push(hoverColors);
    
  i++;
};

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart_cant_ventas"), {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
      labels: datos['labels'],
      datasets: [{
          label: "Population (millions)",
          data: datos['data'],
          datalabels: datos['data_info'],
          backgroundColor: graphColors,
          hoverBackgroundColor: hoverColor,
          borderColor: graphOutlines,
      }]
  },
  options: {
      title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Cantidad de ventas por producto'
      },
      onClick: function(element, dataAtClick) {
          console.log(element);
          console.log(dataAtClick);
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="chart_cant_ventas"></canvas>
```

[***enlace del código en jsfiddler***](https://jsfiddle.net/9jn45gLa/1/)

Comment: Puedes ser un poco mas especifico no logro entender, los datos que mencionas vienen en el JS

Comment: @Dohko19 Disculpa, ya acomode la pregunta.

Comment: Esta mal visto dejar enlaces externos a tu codigo, porque con el tiempo se rompen. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el codigo dejando como referencia el enlace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes de obtener un índice para saber a cuál `datalabels` se debe de seleccionar.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
onClick: function(element, dataAtClick) {
    if(dataAtClick != null && dataAtClick.length > 0) {
        var index = dataAtClick[0]["_index"];
        var objData = this.data.datasets[0].datalabels[index];
        console.log(objData);
    }
}
```

En el `this.data.datasets[0]` se coloca cero, porque solo especificas es la configuraciones un solo dataset.

Te dejo las referencias que utilice:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1169883/Show-value-in-popup-on-doughnut-chart-slice-click

https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/8bras9/getting_onclick_to_call_one_of_your_methods_with/